# Form.ShowDialog in console-app without owner being set

Tags: c#, modal-dialog, console-application

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    ...
    void SoSomething()
    {
        var f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog(null);
    }
    void SoSomethingElse()
    {
        var f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
```

From my current tests it seems those two methods are identical and `ShowDialog` seems to automatically set its owner to the form that called it if not set (argument to `ShowDialog` is `null`).

However I have a console-app that creates such a form. I wonder what the owner of the dialog is in that case. I didn´t find any docs describing what exactly happens when providing `null` to `ShowDialog`.

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner(v=vs.110).aspx) is the only thing I know of regarding the Owner relationship. A dialog without an owner acts like an independent window and should not cause any problems, I think.

Comment: A dialog must always, always have an owner.  If you don't specify one then it goes hunting for one, picking the currently active window that's owned by the process.  That makes code like this brittle, some odds that it can't find a suitable owner and has to fall back to the desktop window.  That's bad, your app loses the foreground when the dialog closes.  Any subsequent window you create might well be invisible, covered by the window owned by another process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,6116) it seems that the program tries to get the active window.

```
IntPtr hWndActive = UnsafeNativeMethods.GetActiveWindow();
IntPtr hWndOwner = owner == null ? hWndActive : Control.GetSafeHandle(owner);
```

For console applications there is none, `hWndActive` is `IntPtr.Zero` and `owner` is null. So the form doesn't have an owner.

Effectively this has [the same behavior](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,6109) as `ShowDialog()` since that just calls:

```
public DialogResult ShowDialog() {
    return ShowDialog(null);
}
```

So basically this is just a form without an owner. Nothing special. It acts like an independent window.

As a side note: you should not open a form from a console application without using `Application.Run(new ...());` It makes sure the Win32 message loop is up and running.

Comment: Quite interesting, thanks for that answer. So `UnsafeNativeMethods.GetActiveWindow()` is the reason why at least in a winforms-app `ShowDialog(null)` and `ShowDialog(myForm)` behave identical as the active window is allways that one that opened the dialog.